# Filter a table based on other two tables Django OMR

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a table with fields email and department_name, another table named Department with a dept_name and a user table. Department table have a manytomany relation to user table. I need to filter first table with departments having user with email columns. Is there anyway to do this in a single query. My query may look like `TempUser.objects.filter(email__in=Department.objects.filter(dept_name="department name from first table").users.value_list('email', flat=True)`

Comment: I tried using F() but its not possible to use it in subquery

Comment: can you please post your models?

Comment: "I need to filter first table with departments having user with email columns"  Sorry, do you mean you want a `QuerySet<Department>` which has at least one `.user` with `email != None`?

Comment: TempUser - email, dept_name
Department- dept_name, users (foreign key)
User - email

These are the model... I need to query TempUser with Departments having user with email in TempUser model

Comment: It's quite hard to read them from the comments, would edit your question and paste them as code snippets please